# Troubleshooting "Intro to tf" tutorial

Tags: ros, permission, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm working through the tf tutorial at http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf, but when I get to Step #5, I get the following error:

```
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks$ rosrun tf view_frames
Listening to /tf for 5.000000 seconds
Done Listening
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/geometry/tf/scripts/view_frames", line 130, in <module>
    generate(dot_graph)
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/geometry/tf/scripts/view_frames", line 85, in generate
    with open('frames.gv', 'w') as outfile:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'frames.gv'
```

Would someone be so kind as to tell me what this error means by "permission" (I have root priveleges but `sudo rosrun tf view_frames` just errored)? And how to go about obtaining that permission?

I'm working on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 10.05 and ROS Diamondback installed. My physical machine has Windows Vista, if that's important.

Thanks,

Khiya

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10439/troubleshooting-%22intro-to-tf%22-tutorial/) by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2011-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to change directory out of /opt/ros... -- this is a system directory, and so you don't have permission to create a file there. I suggest you:

```
$ cd
$ rosrun tf view_frames
```

This will put you in your home directory, and you'll be able to then open the PDF from there.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-06-29**:
Yes, any command run with "sudo" is run as root. If you did an "ls -l" on the directory, you would likely see that "root" was the owner of all the files.

**Comment by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on 2011-06-29**:
Interesting. Yes, I probably did use "sudo" to create the ~/ros_tutorials directory - so "sudo" makes the OS gods think they own whatever "sudo" is creating, and so unless you keep using "sudo" they don't let you edit anything created with "sudo"? Thanks!

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-06-29**:
Did you happen to create the directory as "sudo"? My general rule of thumb with ROS is: except for "apt-get", you shouldn't need sudo, and if you think you need sudo, you're probably doing something wrong.

**Comment by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on 2011-06-29**:
Thanks, that did work. When I first tried this command I was in my ~/ros_tutorials directory, self-created after running through the Intro to ROS tutorials. I received the same error there, even though it's part of my home directory. What's up with that?